# Se puede instalar un proyecto hecho laravel dentro de otro hecho solo con php?

Tags: php, html, laravel

Tengo un proyecto que está hecho en puro php pero el cliente me pide que le integre funcionalidades que me parecen facil de hacer mediante laravel. Es posible fusionar los dos?

Comment: ¿Y por que no pasar lo que tienes hecho en PHP a Laravel?, suena mas simple y lógico

Comment: Lo que pasa esque el sitio está vinculado con otro de mayor peso (es una plataforma de una universidad) y yo no tengo acceso a todo el codigo... es algo complicado.

Comment: Entonces con composer agrega las dependencias de Laravel que requieras en tu proyecto, están en packagist, pues como tal no habrá una respuesta única a lo que pides

Comment: Otra puede ser hacer hacer una api que resuelva eso que dices te parece más facil con laravel, y consumir esa api desde el proyecto en php como consumes un servicio externo.

Comment: No sé que respuesta esperas. Se puede? Si. Cómo? Ni idea, no estás explicando nada específico. Depende de la manera como pretendas pasar de una app a otra: subdominio? Subdirectorio? Que es lo que te parece más fácil c Laravel?